# LibreOffice Writer - How to totally delete table borders?

Tags: libreoffice

I marked all my table's rows and went to "Table properties" there I deleted all borders:

```
style == none, width == 0.00 pt, color == White.
```

Yet, my table still has borders, not black this time, but rather gray.

How can I remove these as well?

### Update:

I now see that it doesn't really matter if I delete these gray lines or not because if I export the document in PDF these do not appear.

Comment: That's correct. The gray lines just show you where they are in case you need to adjust the size, number of cells, etc. It's just for the screen. They don't show when you print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "borders" are called **grid lines**. They are non-printable helping lines. You can toggle their visibility under View --> Gridlines for sheet.

But there really is no reason to do so, if you only care about print output.